# TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value) TypeError: Cannot convert <LenderInvestment: 20000.00> to Decimal

Tags: django

```
class LenderInvestment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    investment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=1000000)
    initial_capital = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, **optional)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.initial_capital)

class LoanDisbursement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    initial_capital = models.OneToOneField(LenderInvestment)
    loan_applicant = models.ForeignKey(LoanApplication)
    money_disbursed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)


def loan_disbursement_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_capital = instance.initial_capital
    money_disbursed = instance.money_disbursed
    initial_capital = Decimal(initial_capital) - Decimal(money_disbursed)
    instance.initial_capital = initial_capital

pre_save.connect(loan_disbursement_receiver, sender=LoanDisbursement)
```

I have two models as shown above inorder to calculate the value from one model instance to another model instance I need help, when I connected as above it gives type error. Looking forward for some positive reply.

Comment: Please fix indentation. Also, have you tried subtracting `money_disbursed` from `initial_capital` *without* converting to decimal?

Comment: without decimal the error is unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'LenderInvestment' and 'Decimal'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two fields called the same thing, and you are getting confused between them. Your signal is called on LoanDisbursement, and that model has a OneToOneField called `initial_capital`. That value can't be converted to Decimal, since it is a *relationship*, not a number.

However, the model it has a relationship to, LenderInvestment, *also* has a field called `initial_capital`. It is *that* value that is a number. You need to follow the relationship in your signal, and use that related instance both when getting and setting the value.

```
def loan_disbursement_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    investment = instance.initial_capital
    investment.initial_capital -= money_disbursed
```

Note a) there is no need to convert these values to Decimal, since they already are; b) there is no need to use intermediate variables; and c) you can use `-=` to do the subtraction inline.

Also note, depending on your use case, you will probably need to call `save` on the investment instance.

Finally, note that this would all be a lot less confusing if you called the OneToOneField what it actually is; eg `lender_investment`.

Comment: I have changed lenderinvestment as you suggested, print is showing subtracted value, but i dont know how to save, i tried many ways not succeeded.

Comment: def loan_disbursement_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    investment = instance.lenderinvestment
    money_disbursed = instance.money_disbursed
    investment.initial_capital -= money_disbursed
    print investment.initial_capital
pre_save.connect(loan_disbursement_receiver, sender=LoanDisbursement)

Comment: You weren't able to do `investment.save()`?

Comment: investment.save() doesn't do anything, instance.investment.save() giving error

Comment: I didn't say to do either of those.